# How to customise naming of symfony 1.4 form elements

Tags: symfony-forms

I know this is possible but I can't seem to find the right search string to get the answer online.

I have MyForm()

and I want to create 5 of these rendered within the same form so I want to change the naming structure of the form elements thus: 
name="forms[1][fieldname1]"
name="forms[1][fieldname2]"

name="forms[2][fieldname1]"
name="forms[2][fieldname2]"

etc 
so that when it is submitted I can just iterate through the $_POST['forms'] array,  binding each one to a MyForm instance and validating.

I'm sure you can customise he naming of fields for symfony forms in some global way rather than going through each widget but I just can't find it on the web.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Solved own problem : $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('my_form[][%s]');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved own problem : 
$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('my_form[][%s]');